# Content border for NSWindow in xcode 4

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, interface-builder

In interface builder for xcode 3.2 NSWindow had property content border to set something like a 'footer' for the app, does anyone know where is it in xcode 4 interface builder?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Probably, but Xcode 4 remains under NDA, so nobody can give you that answer here. Try asking on the developer forums instead.

Answer (score 2):

First select your window and open the 'Right side bar' icon at 'View' on top of Xcode to open Inspector. Then select the 'Measurement' icon in Inspector.

You will see the content border - for both top and bottom, where you can select default sizes or your own sizes for the content border.